# How do I prevent a HTML element from enlarging when there is text inside?

Tags: html, css

I have two columns, the first must have 200px, but no more than 50% of the window, and the second column must take the remainder.

Basically, I want it to behave like the first row: https://jsfiddle.net/vao88dd4/10/

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 50%
}
.right {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">
  <span class="left">LEFT</span>  
  <span class="right">RIGHT</span>
</span>
<span class="box">
  <span class="left">LEFT</span>  
  <span class="right">RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT</span>
</span>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83PNX.png)

The problem is, when there's text in the second column, it will enlarge it, causing the first one to shrink.

How do I make to get the pretended behaviour?

Comment: Do you need all the `left` elements to be the same size as each other even if one changes because of the content?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the left element to become larger when it has text.

Comment: I mean, do you want *all* `left` elements to be equal to each other? Or if they have different amounts of text, is it ok that they are different sizes, once they are no bigger than 200px?

Comment: They are supposed to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .box {
        display: flex;
        background-color: orange;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .left {
        background-color: yellow;
        min-width: 200px;
        flex: 0;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .right {
        background-color: green;
        flex: 1;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .box {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .left {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        .right {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: teal;
        }
    }
</style>
```

1. I added min-width: 200px; on the left span
2. I added matching word wrapping on both left+right
3. I added flex: 0 on the left span which keeps its specified size
4. I added flex: 1 on the right span which causes it to fill any remaining space
5. I removed flex-grow on the right span because of this
6. I added a media query which says when the viewport width goes below 500px, change the box to flex-direction: column; and make the spans 100% width
7. This is minimal changes to get what you are asking for, I think.

HTML (I just added some text, no element changes)

```
<span class="box">
    <span class="left">
        LEFT aosdfnhaskldfn askldnf aklsjdfnk sdg adfh adf
    </span>
    <span class="right">
        RIGHT sfh sfgh srt tj sfgtj sfj fgj
    </span>
</span>

<span class="box">
    <span class="left">
        LEFT sdh sdh sth rth sh
    </span>
    <span class="right">
        RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
        RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
        RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
    </span>
</span>
```

Media queries are super amazing because you get full control over when things change and how, so you can do things you couldn't otherwise. It is very common to have media query breakpoints, so it updates the appearance above/below say 700px, 1024px, 1400px. It takes more work, but you will find it is worth it because your page/site looks great on every device.

As I mentioned in my comment below, make sure you use this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it to go below 200px when the screen becomes smaller.

Comment: @kojow7 Actually I think the OP wants it to be min 200px, but the problem is that the variable width of the `.right` column can cause all of the `.left` divs to have differing widths (see their linked image)

Comment: That makes the column take more than half the screen when it's smaller than 400px.

Comment: You are definitely correct in that it looks subpar once we get around mobile viewport width. I'm going to delete my answer in a minute. I'm working on a better solution.

Comment: I think a good answer here should demonstrate media queries and perhaps mild use of a css grid to establish columns.

Comment: On my screen, this functions pretty solid down to about 180px viewport width. You should also add this to your HTML <head>: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` This will keep the scale the same for mobile devices. It will look mangled without initial-scale=1.0, always use it.

Comment: To test that, press F12 in your browser, and then at the top right, click the mobile button. Notice the difference when you do/dont have that head tag.

Comment: ctrl+shift+m in Chrome to toggle mobile mode

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `table` element or use `display: grid` if you're targeting only the modern browsers.